# Can the Fabric library for Python be used to load C code onto a remote server, then execute it?

Tags: python-2.7, fabric

If so, any general tips as I start reading the Fabric documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask fabric to upload the source, compile and execute it, but you could pre-compile it locally (keep the binary file ready), upload it, and then execute it remotely. Take a look into the `put` and `run` operations:

> [fabric.operations.put(*args, **kwargs)](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put)
>
> [fabric.operations.run(*args, **kwargs)](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run)